# How to ignore a file in git tree without removing it

Tags: git, github

I've a git repository of an Android package and I want to ignore `bin`and `gen` folders. I added them to the `.gitignore` after the folder existed.

Now if I use `git rm`, the files in `bin` and `res` will get deleted. Is there any way to ignore and remove these folders from version control without deleting the files from the hard drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use [`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm.html):

```
git rm -r --cached bin
git rm -r --cached gen
```

The `--cached` will make sure they are still on the disk, but no longer in git index: they will then be ignored (add and commit that change).
`-r` allows recursive removal when a leading directory name is given.

Answer (score 2):

Open the .git/info/exclude file in a text editor and add the folder to ignore. This file remains private to you. You can also create a .gitignore file in the repository's root directory, outside the .git directory and write the folder entry there. Then add this file to the repository to share with others what content should be ignored, should others have this directory-to-ignore in their repository too.
If you already committed this directory then just remove it with git rm -r --cached, commit the deletion and mark the directory ignored as I described above. You might want to make a backup of the directory before you wipe it.